# JQuery ajax error function is executed even if query is successful

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

I'm trying to learn JQuery - and I have a small problem with ajax. I'm trying to populate a javascript array with values returned from an XML response from a page.
Here's my main page (ajax.html):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/fiber.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Ajax</p>
<script>
var ringType = new Array();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

fiber.js is this:

```
//process things for fiber map
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
// do stuff when DOM is ready

//populate and display ringType
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "ajaxHelper.pl",
  data: {
      getRingTypes: "1",
      },
  dataType: "xml",
  success: function(xml) {
      //if the query was successfull,
      alert("Got an xml object:"+$(xml));
      $(xml).find("ringType").each( function(){
          alert("Received reply "+$(this).text());
          var type = $(this).html(); //save the value
          //append to ringType array
          ringType.push(type);
      });
  },
  error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
      alert(xhr.status);
      alert(thrownError);
  }
 });
 for(var i=0; i<ringType.length; i++){
    document.write("<br>"+ringType[i]);
 }

});
```

ajaxHelper.pl generates this XML (without the backslashes in \?) (as content-type text/xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <\?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"\?>
    <ringType>IA</ringType>
    <ringType>IL</ringType>
    <ringType>IN</ringType>
    <ringType>IR</ringType>
    <ringType>RT</ringType>
```

The problem is, every time I load ajax.html, the ajax query is successful, but the error function is executed! xhr.status = 200 (meaning the query was ok) and thrownException is undefined.

Comment: Sorry, the xml didn't paste correctly. Here goes again (with some spaces):
< ? xml version= "1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ? >
< ringType > IA < / ringType >
< ringType > IL < / ringType >
< ringType > IN < / ringType >
< ringType > IR < / ringType >
< ringType > RT < / ringType >

Comment: Try putting <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> at the top of the output XML document, if you haven't already

Comment: if you open the ajaxHelper.pl file in you browser (http://mywebapp/ajaxHelper.pl), does the browser recognize the response from the file as XML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this happen in all browsers?

1) You can use *complete* instead of success and error to handle the status. Use an if to check the XHR return status and branch accordingly.

http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options

Comment: This behavior happens on all browsers. I will try to use complete instead of success and I'll let you know.

Comment: I've added the complete function and when I check it's status, I get "parsererror" - meaning the xml I send is not valid. At least now I know where to keep digging. Thank you!

Comment: Apparently XMLs have to have defining xsd's to be valid. My code will not work without them. Now (that I have created the missing definition), all works as expected.

Answer (score 5):

via http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/23679594ebe128a9

> the server could return an XML document with a 200 status code.  But if the browser can not parse the document a parseerror will occur and jQuery's error handler will be invoked.

Make sure you're returning valid xml :)

Comment: Had this problem, but with JSON results. Fix was the same though and worked: return valid JSON and the browser is happy, calling the right event on return.

Answer (score 1):

AJAX is Asynchronous. Meaning that the $.ajax function will start a request the ajaxHelper.pl. In the meantime it continues to execute your code. The request has no chance to return before you reach the next line after $.ajax(...)

```
for(var i=0; i<ringType.length; i++){...
```

So I suppose you're getting an exception that ringType is not defined...? And that might be why the error function is triggered.

Comment: Fair enough, but it doesn't even trigger the alerts from starting the success function...

Comment: When an error is thrown, the script will stop executing. I haven't looked at the jQuery internals how they handle the exceptions, but just try moving the for loop inside the callback.